# When can an answer be deleted by someone else?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I ask this because I answered a question where the user put into a comment next to my answer that he did not want me to answer his question, so I should remove my (correct) answer.

He then removed the question. How can I make sure that my answer is not removed like this?

Is this personal aspect part of SO?

Comment: Do you have a link to that question? In any case, as soon as your answer receives upvotes, the OP of the question can't simply remove it. And you don't have to delete your answer when someone asks you to do this.

Comment: Ok, he put it up once again: ... I wanted to send you the link but the user once again removed his question since I answered it, before my answer got upvoted. (My SO account is @BarnabasSzabolcs and the user is the question had [matlab] tag on it)

Comment: However I tried to protect the question by upvoting it, did not help...

Comment: Your answer would need an upvote. Not the question. But I'm assuming this is the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431369/indices-of-a-matrix

Comment: See. Thanks anyway, Bart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You as the author of an answer can delete your answer at any point. Apart from that, your answer can only directly be deleted by a moderator, should they find (possible through flagging by other users) that your answer is not really an answer, or through voting by 3 users with a reputation >20k, should your answer be negatively scored.

The other option is for your answer to be "deleted" as part of the deletion of a question. Again, moderation can be at play here, but the OP of a question can also still delete his question should none of the answers have reached a positive score.

There isn't really a defence against answer deletion as such, apart from contributing a good answer which receives upvotes.

At no point do you have to delete your answer because anyone asks you to do so. This is entirely up to you. Should you have been pressured into deleting your answer then this is inappropriate. If persistently pressured into deleting it, a flag for moderator attention might be appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks, also thanks for saving my answer(question) there.

Comment: One more thing worth to mention: 6 offensive flags (user with meager 15 rep can start flagging) will auto delete a post no matter how high or low is its score and even give -100 rep penalty.